# Android GoogleCast Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.media.MediaRouterGlobalMediaRouter

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cast

Im compiling ChromeCast this Github Project [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android).in Eclipse environment.I have latest dependencies installed on the project.

[image]
[image]

When i running the project,its throws this run time error.

```
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$1
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.<init>(MediaRouter.java:1628)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.getInstance(MediaRouter.java:246)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.BaseCastManager.<init>(BaseCastManager.java:189)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager.<init>(VideoCastManager.java:196)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.VideoCastManager.initialize(VideoCastManager.java:223)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.CastApplication.onCreate(CastApplication.java:43)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4280)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:143)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   05-05 11:25:08.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17660):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)


   05-05 11:25:08.303: E/dalvikvm(17660): Could not find class 'android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$1', referenced from method android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.<init>
   05-05 11:25:08.303: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1180 (Landroid/support/v7/media/MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$1;) in Landroid/support/v7/media/MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter;
   05-05 11:25:08.303: D/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0035
   05-05 11:25:08.303: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat;)
   05-05 11:25:08.313: I/dalvikvm(17660): Could not find method android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken, referenced from method android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.getMediaSessionToken
   05-05 11:25:08.313: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2967: Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat;.getSessionToken ()Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat$Token;
   05-05 11:25:08.313: D/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0011
   05-05 11:25:08.323: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat;)
   05-05 11:25:08.323: I/dalvikvm(17660): Could not find method android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.getRemoteControlClient, referenced from method android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.setMediaSessionCompat
   05-05 11:25:08.323: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2966: Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat;.getRemoteControlClient ()Ljava/lang/Object;
   05-05 11:25:08.323: D/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000a
   05-05 11:25:08.323: I/dalvikvm(17660): Could not find method android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.getMediaSession, referenced from method android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.setMediaSessionCompat
   05-05 11:25:08.323: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2965: Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat;.getMediaSession ()Ljava/lang/Object;
   05-05 11:25:08.323: D/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001e
   05-05 11:25:08.333: I/dalvikvm(17660): Could not find method android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.getRemoteControlClient, referenced from method android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.setMediaSessionCompat
   05-05 11:25:08.333: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2966: Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat;.getRemoteControlClient ()Ljava/lang/Object;
   05-05 11:25:08.333: D/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0032
   05-05 11:25:08.333: I/dalvikvm(17660): Could not find method android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.addOnActiveChangeListener, referenced from method android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter.setMediaSessionCompat
   05-05 11:25:08.333: W/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2964: Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat;.addOnActiveChangeListener (Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat$OnActiveChangeListener;)V
   05-05 11:25:08.333: D/dalvikvm(17660): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0044
   05-05 11:25:08.333: I/dalvikvm(17660): Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/media/MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$1; interface 510 'Landroid/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat$OnActiveChangeListener;'
   05-05 11:25:08.333: W/dalvikvm(17660): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/media/MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$1;' failed
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check `buildpath`. Specifically `Order and Export` section if your `support library` is checked

Comment: there is no option to select support Libraries ..please see the screen shot

Comment: When i say `support library`, i mean `v7-appcompat library`

Comment: i checked that "v7-appcompat library" and run it.but still displays same error

Comment: ok go to your projects and check for `v7-appcompat jar file`. Right click on it and `Build Path-> Add to Buildpath`. Also can you upload a screenshot of `libraries` section?

Comment: in actionbar compact v7 project and mediarouter project i have added v7-appcompat jar to the build path. but when i compiling the project "VideoBrowserActivity" its shows this  ---             Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;
[2015-05-05 12:03:33 - VideoBrowserActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;

Comment: From the error i see that that your project contains multiple `support-v7 library`. One is in your project and another is in the library which you have added in your project. Just remove the one library which you have added in your project. And then clean and run your application.

Comment: Added answer for someone else having same issue. Glad you solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your projects and check for `v7-appcompat jar` file. Right click on it and `Build Path-> Add to Buildpath`
2. Check `buildpath`. Specifically `Order and Export` section if your
   `v7-appcompat library` is checked
3. Check if your project contains **multiple `support-v7 library`**. One is
   in *your project and another is in the library which you have added
   in your project*. Just **remove** the one library which you have added in
   your project. And then **clean and run your application**.